# When a DLL is not found while P/Invoking, how can I get a message about the specific unmanaged DLL that is missing?

Tags: pinvoke

When you link to an unmanaged library (say 'A.dll') which in turn links to another library ('B.dll'), and B.dll is missing, you will get a run-time error message about failing to load 'B.dll'.

But when you P/Invoke into 'A.dll' from managed code, you'll get a general exception of this form:

Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'A.dll': The specified module could not be found.

How can I get an error message that pinpoints the specific unmanaged dll file that failed to load, when p/invoking from managed code ?

Comment: I wonder if Process Monitor from sysinternals would be of any help in this situation. It would maybe point to the missing DLL.

Comment: Well jeez, you can't expect the *computer* to figure out something tricky like that, when a computer programmer could spend half an hour doing it by hand, and anyway, this would never happen with deployed software.  Right? It seems bizarre, but don't you sometimes wonder if the folks at Microsoft actually understand what computers are for?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any specific API you can use to pinpoint why `LoadLibrary` (the underlying Win32 API) failed for 'A.dll'. I recommend the use of a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to troubleshoot DLL loading errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can get this in the form of an exception.  When I run into this problem I usually try and open the DLL with depends.exe.  It's pretty good and reporting missing dependencies that exist if the DLL is simply loaded from it's current location.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get an answer from the exception, but you can do it (with a lot of work) through Process Monitor.  This article discusses how and also includes a tool to scan Process Monitor logs to find the specific problem.

http://tech.blinemedical.com/debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

The Fusion Log Viewer is a good tool to debug assembly loading problems in .NET apps.

For identifying general file-load problems, you can use Process Monitor.